# DataTables Select event original click target

Tags: jquery, datatables, jquery-events

[The docs for the `select` event](https://datatables.net/reference/event/select) say that the first argument is a jQuery event.  However, when I inspect both `target` and `currentTarget` on that event they both refer to the table element.

Is there a way from the `select` event to determine what the specific element in the table was that was clicked to select the row?  I need to do different things in the select callback based on what was clicked.  For example, if a checkbox was clicked as opposed to just a td cell, I need to be able to tell.

Comment: Doesn't second argument of `select` callback function refer to DataTables api instance (row in your case)?

Comment: It does, but I need to know the specific element that was clicked.  I've updated the question to clarify a bit more what I'm looking for.

Comment: To the best of my knowledge, you can't do more than custom `select` event offers to you (get particular row, column or cell) as the very first line reads in the doc you refer to. However, you may use your own `click` events to grab necessary data.

Comment: @YevgenGorbunkov In my particular case that's what I ended up doing.  Click events on checkboxes select or deselect the row to put it back (not ideal, but works in my case since row select/deselect handlers don't do much). I think you're right - the dt event just doesn't give us that information, sadly.

Answer (score 1):

Use event handler fourth argument `indexes` (see **Examples** in [`select`](https://datatables.net/reference/event/select) event documentation) to get selected rows, columns or cells.

For example:

```
var table = $('#example').DataTable();

table.on( 'select', function ( e, dt, type, indexes ) {
    if ( type === 'row' ) {
        var $rows = table.rows( indexes ).nodes().to$();
    }
} );
```

Comment: I've added a bit more clarification to the question.  What I need to know is the specific element that was clicked within the cell.